# Splitting a String using multiple delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string using python. I have successfully done it for one variable, but finding it hard to do it for 2.

The String :

```
Paragraph 4-2 says. i am going home$ early- Yes.
```

I need the output to be

```
Paragraph 4-2 says
i am going home 
early
Yes
```

The sentence should split from `.`, `$` and `-` (But when it's between 2 numbers (4-2) it shouldn't split)

How can i do this?

```
text.split('.')
```

**UPDATE**

The new output should be like :

```
Paragraph 4-2 says.
i am going home$ 
early-
Yes.
```

Comment: Would `4$2` need to be split? What about `4.2`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think this is a duplicate of that; this question has more to it.

Comment: @arshajii: fair enough, retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> import re
>>> st='Paragraph 4-2 says. i am going home$ early- Yes.'
>>> [m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r'(.*?[.$\-])(?:\s+|$)',st)]
['Paragraph 4-2 says.', 'i am going home$', 'early-', 'Yes.']
```

If you are not going to modify the match group at all (with strip or something) you can also just use findall with the same regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(.*?[.$\-])(?:\s+|$)',st)
['Paragraph 4-2 says.', 'i am going home$', 'early-', 'Yes.']
```

The regex is explained [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/vW8rK2), but in summary:

```
(.*?[.$\-])  is the capture group containing:
 .*?          Any character (except newline) 0 to infinite times [lazy] 
    [.$\-]   Character class matching .$- one time

(?:\s+|$)    Non-capturing Group containing:
   \s+        First alternate: Whitespace [\t \r\n\f] 1 to infinite times [greedy] 
      |        or
       $      Second alternate: end of string
```

Depending on your strings, you may need to change the regex to `(.*?[.$\-])(?:[ ]+|$)` if you don't want to match `\r\n\f` with the `\s`

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Paragraph 4-2 says. i am going home$ early- Yes'
>>>
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\d)\s*[.$-]\s*(?!\d)', s)
['Paragraph 4-2 says', 'i am going home', 'early', 'Yes']
```

- `\s*[.$-]\s*` matches any of `.`,`$` or `-` surrounded by 0 or more spaces (`\s*`).
- `(?<!\d)` is a negative-lookbehind to ensure that the match is not preceded by a digit.
- `(?!\d)` is a negative-lookahead to ensure that the match is not followed by a digit.

You can read more about lookarounds [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: No need to escape dot in character class.

Comment: @SteveP. Fair enough; I added some explanation.

Comment: Is there a way for me to append the split character at the end of the sentence ? (`-.$`)

Comment: @user1315906 Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look. I have given the expected output.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> re.split('(?<=\D)[.$-](?=\D|$)', s)
['Paragraph 4-2 says', ' i am going home', ' early', ' Yes']
>>>
```

`(?<\D)[.$-](?=\D)` will get the .$-, not followed or proceded by intergers. And the lookahead and lookbehind won't consume any string. So the string will be splitted only the .$-, without the numbers surrounded by it.

**Edit:**

```
>>> re.findall('.*?(?<=\D)[.$-](?=[\D]|$)', s)
['Paragraph 4-2 says.', ' i am going home$', ' early-', ' Yes.']
```

Comment: I was also thinking of using `findall`, if i replace split with find all, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think split is a good choice. You have fixed format. For findall, it seems there will be a more complicated regex.@user1315906

Comment: I was thinking of having the `.$-` characters at the end of the sentence. If so what change should i do (anyway, this wasn't asked in my original post)

Comment: What do you mean? If `.$-` is at the end the string, the split will also work except there will be a empty string in the result list. I don't think that will be a problem.

Comment: I have updated my question. I have updated the expected output in my post. please have a look.

Comment: So the dot after says should also be preserved?

Comment: Yes, the `.` `$` and the `-` character used to split should be preserved

Comment: Update my answer. Please check.